# Правильно ли в django делать виджеты через пользовательские шаблонные теги?

Tags: django

В Yii можно сделать виджет, унаследовав новый объект от CWidget а потом где-нибудь в шаблоне вставить его php кодом:

```
$this->widget('application.components.LeftMenu');
```

Таким образом мы разбиваем код на отдельные элементы. Изучая джанго я пытался понять как сделать то же на нём. Пришел к выводу, что такие вещи реализуют с помощью пользовательских тегов. Например, чтоб сделать левое меню нужно создать библиотеку тегов, создать тег, например {% left_menu %}, подключить данную библиотеку к родительскому шаблону, и вставить в нём данный тег в нужное место. А html код менюшки рендерим в коде тега, отдавая строку с ним.

Скажите, это правильный подход в джанго, и если правильный то всегда ли? Или такое решается другими методами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что вы описали реализуется с помощью шаблонов. В [context_processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) пишется код, формирующий меню (если оно у вас динамическое) и в любом месте шаблона выводится само меню, либо подключается отдельный шаблон с помощью тега [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include).

Но если вы хотите выделить отдельный виджет в самостоятельную сущность, то следует поступить как вы и написали, создав пользовательский тег. Это удобно если вы, например, хотите делится этим кодом и сделать его подключение максимально простым. Но не стоит таким образом разбивать свой сайт на логические блоки.

Comment: я понял примерно как написать контекстный процессор, но у меня возник вопрос. Контекстный процессор - это функция которая добавляет переменные в текущий контекст. Например мы формируем одно меню одной такой функцией, и другое меню в другой. На одном url-е вонтроллер рендерит шаблон с первым меню, на другом url-е будет шаблон с другим меню. Вопрос - в обоих случаях будут срабатывать оба контроллера контекста несмотря на то, что в каждом случае будет использоваться только один набор данных? То есть контроллеры будут выполнять лишнюю работу, или я что-то неправильно понял?

Comment: Честно говоря не совсем понял вопрос. Но суть в общем вот в чем: все контекстные процессоры выполняются всегда при каждом запросе. И если на какой либо странице вам не нужно меню, то этот контроллер выполнит лишнюю работу. Я написал про контекстные процессоры потому что обычно на сайте одно меню и почти нет страниц где его нет.

Comment: Ну допустим я хочу создать "виджет" не для меню а к примеру для формы фидбека. Для неё нужно готовить данные, а присутствует она не на всех страницах, а скажем на половине из них. Если бы я использовал контекстные процессоры я бы просто писал в шаблоне {% include "feedback_form.html" %} но тогда, судя по тому что вы сказали, в половине случаев, когда нам не нужна эта форма процессор будет срабатывать впустую. Есть какой-то метод, позволяющий исключить холостые срабатывания контекстного процессора? Мне что, в каждом представлении вручную указывать процессоры для каждого include-ного шаблона?

Comment: Скажите, по какому принципу вы будете вставлять ваш виджет в шаблоны? Если это абсолютно рандомная логика то решение с кастомным тегом выглядит неплохо.